# split json log of type array that starts with [] into multiple arrays based on the number of elements in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, lambda, split

I am trying to create multiple files by reading my JSON log file and separate file has to be created per each element in my JSON array. Any help would be appreciated.

Approach : Able to read the json log file using `json.load()` and read the number of elements inside the json array and then copy first 5 elements in to  file1 as an json array , and rest 5 into second file as an json array and so on till the length of my json log file array.
update :
I got it working till splitting the list/array in to 10 individual lists/array till end of the file. now have to write those list to separate json.gz file and upload to s3.

````
import json


json_data = json.dumps([
  {
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2"
  },
  {
    "d": "3"
  },
  {
    "d": "4"
  },
  {
    "e": "5"
  },
  {
    "e": "6"
  },
  {
    "e": "7"
  },
  {
    "e": "8"
  },
  {
    "e": "9"
  },
  {
    "e": "5"
  },
  {
    "e": "10"
  },
  {
    "e": "11"
  },
  {
    "e": "12"
  },
  {
    "s": "y"
  },
  {
    "s": "y"
  },
  {
    "s": "y"
  },
  {
    "s": "y"
  },
  {
    "s": "y"
  },
  {
    "s": "y"
  },
  {
    "s": "y"
  },
  {
    "s": "y"
  },
  {
    "s": "y"
  },
  {
    "s": "y"
  },
  {
    "s": "y"
  },
  {
    "s": "y"
  },
  {
    "s": "y"
  },
  {
    "s": "y"
  },
  {
    "s": "y"
  },
  {
    "abc": [
      {
        "te": "tre"
      }
    ]
  }
])

item_dict = json.loads(json_data)
lens = len(item_dict)
first = 0
last = 10
b = item_dict[first:last]
#print (item_dict[0:2])
print (lens)
for i in range(lens):
    if last < lens:
       n = 0
       res = item_dict[first:last]
       print(range(lens))
       print(res)
       first = last 
       last = first + 10
       i = i + 1 
       print(first)
       print(last)
       print(i)
       if last > lens:

          diff = last-lens
          last = last-diff 

          print("second" + str(first))
          print("second" + str(last))
          ins = item_dict[first:last] 
          print(ins)```

my json log file:

```[
  {
    "id": 1000,
    "type": "BigBox",
    "name": "Mall of America",
    "address": "340 W Market",
    "address2": "",
    "city": "Bloomington",
    "state": "MN",
    "zip": "55425",
    "location": {
      "lat": 44.85466,
      "lon": -93.24565
    },
    "hours": "Mon: 10-9:30; Tue: 10-9:30; Wed: 10-9:30; Thurs: 10-9:30; Fri: 10-9:30; Sat: 10-9:30; Sun: 11-7",
    "services": [
      "Geek Squad Services",
      "Best Buy Mobile",
      "Best Buy For Business"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1002,
    "type": "BigBox",
    "name": "Tempe Marketplace",
    "address": "1900 E Rio Salado Pkwy",
    "address2": "",
    "city": "Tempe",
    "state": "AZ",
    "zip": "85281",
    "location": {
      "lat": 33.430729,
      "lon": -111.89966
    },
    "hours": "Mon: 10-9; Tue: 10-9; Wed: 10-9; Thurs: 10-9; Fri: 10-10; Sat: 10-10; Sun: 10-8",
    "services": [
      "Windows Store",
      "Geek Squad Services",
      "Best Buy Mobile",
      "Best Buy For Business"
    ]}
  ]```
````

Comment: What have you written so far?  It isn't clear what part of this you are having trouble with.

Comment: Here is the working solution till it get to split the json list into multiple lists